# x-robots tag for query string parameter

Tags: regex, apache, x-robots-tag

I want to block a query string url's in .htaccess using x-robots tag. The url's are something like:

```
https://www.example.com/test?limit=60
https://www.example.com/test?limit=45
https://www.example.com/test?limit=all
```

I need to block the `?limit=xxx`

Ive tried something like this but it doesnt work:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<Files "^limit=?$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Doesn't `^` mean "start of the string" there? If so, of cource it won't work, no URI would start with `limit=?`.

Comment: Ive tried all sorts e.g "limit=*" and nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^limit=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=NOINDEX_HEADER:1] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" env=NOINDEX_HEADER
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions don't work like that. Some pertinent differences:

- `?` and `*` are quantifiers, not catch-all "match anything" tokens.
- `^` matches the beginning of the string.

This should work instead:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<Files "\?(.*&)?limit=(\d+|all)(&.*)$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How would i write it to block multiple query strings eg:

https://www.example.com/?c2c_panels=4959
https://www.example.com/?c2c_finish=4708

?

Comment: @chappers You can probably duplicate the `<Files>` tag for that.